# Load ICollection from ICollection Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have these models which all of them are a one to many relation in succession.

ListaAbastecimento > ReferenciaAbastecimento > EtiquetaAbastecimento

```
[Table(name: "hListasAbastecimento")]
public class ListaAbastecimento
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ColaboradorId { get; set; }   
    [ForeignKey("ColaboradorId")]
    public virtual Colaborador Colaborador { get; set; }

    public string UAP { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ReferenciaAbastecimento> Referencias { get; set; }
}




    [Table(name: "hReferenciasAbastecimento")]
    public class ReferenciaAbastecimento
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string Referencia { get; set; }
        public int? QtdAbastecimento { get; set; }
        public int? QtdCaixas { get; set; }
        public int? QtdPecasPorCaixa { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EtiquetaAbastecimento> Etiquetas { get; set; }
    }




[Table(name: "hEtiquetasAbastecimento")]
    public class EtiquetaAbastecimento
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? EtiquetaFIFO { get; set; }
        public int? Qtd { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string Localizacao { get; set; }

        public int ReferenciaAbstecimentoId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ReferenciaAbstecimentoId")]
        public virtual ReferenciaAbastecimento ReferenciaAbastecimento { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is what i have tried, however the theninclude does not find the properties

```
   var abastecimentosList = await _context.ListasAbastecimento
            .Include(la => la.Referencias)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.Etiquetas) // can't find Etiquetas property
            .ToListAsync();
```

this does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ThenInclude` on Many-to-Many relations is supported by Entity Framework Core itself, and compiler should be able to cope with the presented code. However, there is/was a [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237) in Intellisense and Visual Studio(s), which didn't properly display properties you can use. (in your case `Etiquetas`). Can confirm, it is fixed in VS 2019 (16.2.0 Preview 1.0) version.